# In 2D a square matrix is a rotation of the plane, can $n \times n$ matrices be thought of as rotations in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations

> In 2D a square matrix is a rotation of the plane, can $n \times n$ matrices be thought of as rotations in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I just want to clarify some of my intuitions about (square) matrices...

Comment: It can be construed as a degeneracy, as singular matrices, right?

Comment: There are plenty of non-degenerate matrices that do not represent rotation. Take any diagonal matrix other than identity.

Comment: Perhaps a more accurate way is to say square matrices in 2D deform the plane "linearly"?

Comment: But can I think of dim-n square matrices as consisting only of:  rotations, reflections, stretching, of dim-n Euclidean space?  What are the exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Not all matrices are rotations. Rotation matrices in 2D are of the form $\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta &  - \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$.

For example, the matrix $2I$ is not a rotation -- it just scales up the vector to twice its length. And a reflection isn't a rotation.

One can define rotations as matrices which are orthogonal (their transpose is their inverse) and have determinant 1.

Answer (score 1):

A square matrix is not always a rotation of the plane : take $$s=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$ which is a symetry. The rotations are only 
$$R=\Big\{\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\mid\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]\Big\}.$$

Comment: Perhaps I should say:  square matrices are rotations + reflections + stretching of the plane?  Can that intuition be generalized to 3D and above?

Comment: @YanKingYin Yes, see [Singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).